# One time salts and server password comparison

Tags: security, hash, authentication, password-protection, password-storage

I've read that one of the more secure ways to authenticate a user is to use one time salts when hashing the password. What I don't get is:

If the client generates a new salt every session, won't the resulting salt+password hash be different every session? If so, how will the server be able to compare the sent password with it's stored password? Is there a way for servers to compare different hashes and still be able to discern that the same password was used?

(Disclaimer: I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel/write a login protocol (I know, I know: use SSL/TLS). I'm just curious as to the high level functioning of login protocols)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to generate the salt only once and may every time the password been changed.

The client needs not to store the salt anywhere or even been aware of that. The salt will be stored by the server - along with the hash.

Its recommended that you store the hash and the salt in two different databases..

Comment: Why do you store the hash and the salt in two databases? This would be basically the same as splitting the hash and storing the halves in separate databases. For a very few attacks it might protect a little better, but I'd consider it much more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: There is no such thing called 'ultimate security'.. Its another step to keep intruders a step away..

Comment: You could split the key into three pieces and put it into three databases. Or one database per byte. You need to think about what kind of attack gives the attacker access to one database but not the other one. Those are the only attacks you're protecting yourself from. Most attacks of this kind don't get access to just one database. They get access to the app, or they get access to the machine. That's why I consider this complexity for its own sake rather than actual security.

Comment: Its all about finding the balance... defence in depth

Answer (score 3):

you only generate a new salt when the user sets the password initially. Then you save the salt along with the password hash.

Comment: How does the client store the salt? As a cookie?

Comment: the client doesn't store the salt. the client provides a username and a password, then you look up the salt and the hash, hash the password with the salt and check if it matches the hash that you have stored.